# Problem while pulling image from a private insecure registry

Tags: linux, docker, docker-image

I am running linux on oracle virtual box. I am trying to pull **ldap** image from on of the private repos of my organization i.e.

```
http://161.85.19.106:8080/repo/ldap/tag/sig-markets-phoenix-customer-2.1.0
```

In order to pull this image from the registry i am using the following command

```
sudo docker pull 161.85.19.106:8080/repo/ldap/:sig-markets-phoenix-customer-2.1.0
```

At first i was getting the following error

```
error response from daemon: Get https:/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

so i added the ip address and port combo to my **daemon.json**.  Moreover i was working behind proxy so i  commented out the proxy resolutions here **etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf** and restarted the daemon and docker.

Now while i am trying to run the above command i get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  <title>The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>\n  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\">\n  <style>\n  .rails-default-error-page {\n    background-color: #EFEFEF;\n    color: #2E2F30;\n    text-align: center;\n    font-family: arial, sans-serif;\n    margin: 0;\n  }\n\n  .rails-default-error-page div.dialog {\n    width: 95%;\n    max-width: 33em;\n    margin: 4em auto 0;\n  }\n\n  .rails-default-error-page div.dialog > div {\n    border: 1px solid #CCC;\n    border-right-color: #999;\n    border-left-color: #999;\n    border-bottom-color: #BBB;\n    border-top: #B00100 solid 4px;\n    border-top-left-radius: 9px;\n    border-top-right-radius: 9px;\n    background-color: white;\n    padding: 7px 12% 0;\n    box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.17);\n  }\n\n  .rails-default-error-page h1 {\n    font-size: 100%;\n    color: #730E15;\n    line-height: 1.5em;\n  }\n\n  .rails-default-error-page div.dialog > p {\n    margin: 0 0 1em;\n    padding: 1em;\n    background-color: #F7F7F7;\n    border: 1px solid #CCC;\n    border-right-color: #999;\n    border-left-color: #999;\n    border-bottom-color: #999;\n    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;\n    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;\n    border-top-color: #DADADA;\n    color: #666;\n    box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.17);\n  }\n  </style>\n</head>\n\n<body class=\"rails-default-error-page\">\n  <!-- This file lives in public/404.html -->\n  <div class=\"dialog\">\n    <div>\n      <h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>\n      <p>You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.</p>\n    </div>\n    <p>If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.</p>\n  </div>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

I had also done a docker logout as i thought it might be failing due to bad credentials.

Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: What if you curl 161.85.19.106:8080/repo/ldap/:sig-markets-phoenix-customer-2.1.0? Seems like it's not a problem related to Docker if you already configured the Docker Daemon's proxy settings

Comment: I get the html body of the link

Comment: Which html body?

Comment: the html body of the link  http://161.85.19.106:8080/repo/ldap/tag/sig-markets-phoenix-customer-2.1.0